# Div Height/Overflow issue

Tags: css, html

The problem I'm having is I have two divs at the top of my page, one contains a repeating blue background, the other contains a background image.

I have to set the height of both divs in order for them to expand vertically, the don't expand with the content. I have that form on the right hand side set to overflow. Which I believe is what's causing the problem.

I have tried not having the height css in the code, but it still won't expand vertically.

In order to get the backgrounds to even show up I have to manually set the height.

This is the page: http://www.repipespecialists.com/landing/google/repiping.html

This is the CSS code:

```
#top_container {
    width:100%;
    height:1040px;
    background-image:url(../images/top_bg_repeat.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#83b4e9;
}

#top_header {
    width:1200px;
    height:1040px;
    background-image:url(../images/header_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#83b4e9;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Could you please post a picture of what you have versus what you're trying to get? A code snippet of the relevant markup and CSS (or a simplified sample) would be very helpful as well.

Comment: I am trying to get the top_container and top_header divs, to automatically expand vertically with the content. As opposed to me having to specify a height

Answer (score 1):

I agree with WDan in that the issue you are having is due to your use of `float: left` and `float: right` on the `left_content` and `right_content` `div` elements.

When you use `float` on an element, you are basically removing it from the normal flow of the document. By default, elements will appear on the page in whatever order you specify in the markup. Using `float` (or things like `position: absolute`) will remove the element from this "order", or "document flow", such that the floated element will be ignored when placing other elements in their default position on the page.

**Since the space used by these floated elements are ignored, the `top_header` `div` does not take the floated element's size into account when determining its own size. This is why your div is not automatically expanding.**

Another alternative to `float` is to use `display: inline-block`. Here are some links you can read to learn more about the differences:

- http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block
- http://www.onderhond.com/blog/work/inline-block-vs-float/
- http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/
- http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you use float in 'left_content' and 'right_content'

Use “overflow: hidden” in the wrapper div.